# Python implementing a variadic concatenation operator

Tags: python, performance, recursion, optimization, concatenation

CLARIFICATIONS:

I just realized my definition and code below might be wrong, because they don't take into account nested lists. I really want the ultimate result from `concatenate` to be either an object which is not a list, or a list of more than 1 objects that are not lists (so no nested lists). And the empty list should become the object Empty.

---

But it is possible for the user to provide an input consisting of nested lists, in such a case I need them to be denested. Apologies for not being clear on this.

I have objects of a certain type (which can have Empty as value too), and I have a binary concatenation operator on these objects that satisfies the following axioms (here [A, B] means the list containing A and B):

```
concatenate2(Empty, A) = concatenate2(A, Empty) = A  
concatenate2(A, [B, C]) = concatenate2([A, B], C) = [A, B, C]  
concatenate2(A, B) = [A, B] (if A, B do not match any of the previous cases).
```

Now I want to also have a concatenation of arbitrarily many terms:

```
concatenate([]) = Empty  
concatenate([A]) = A  
concatenate([A, B]) = concatenate2(A, B)  
concatenate([A, B, ...]) = concatenate([concatenate2(A, B), ...])
```

I would like to implement these operators in a way that minimizes the number of list copy operations, but I am not sure how to do this best in Python.

My current idea was to do something like this:

```
def concatenate2(A, B):
    if A == Empty:
        return B

    if B == Empty:
        return A

    if type(A) == list:
        return concatenate(A + [B])

    if type(B) == list:
        return concatenate([A] + B)

    return [A, B]

def concatenate(terms):
    if terms == []:
        return Empty

    if len(terms) == 1:
        return terms[0]

    if len(terms) == 2:
        return concatenate2(terms[0], terms[1])

    return concatenate(concatenate2(terms[0], terms[1]) + terms[2:])
```

This looks pretty nice and clear, but I don't know how well it stands in terms of performance and memory usage. I am worried it might cause too many list copies during each [...] + [...] operation.

Is there a better way to implement these operations?

Note that ultimately only the `concatenate` operation is really required. The `concatenate2` operator was used to give a nice recursive definition, but if someone can propose a more efficient solution that does not use it, I would accept it too.

Comment: What should `concatenate2([A, B], [C, D])` do? (This design seems to mix up types in a way that will just lead to headaches down the line.)

Comment: It should return [A, B, C, D] (assuming none of these are lists).

Comment: So you want to flatten nested lists as well?

Comment: Yes, I just realized my definition above might be wrong, because it doesn't take into account nested lists. I really want the ultimate result from `concatenate` to be an object which is not a list, or a list of such objects (so no nested lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be wanting is not just variadic, but also has a *mixed type signature*.

Suppose that we want to define some `concatenate_all(*args)` function that concatenates all arguments thrown at it.

*If* you agree that all arguments of `concatenate_all` are sequences, we can form a single sequence out of them, and fold-left it with `concatenate`:

```
import itertools

# Pretend that concatenate_all is [[A]] -> [A]
def concatenate_all(*seqs):
  all_seqs = itertools.chain(*seqs)
  return reduce(lambda acc, x: concatenate(acc, x), all_seqs, EMPTY)
```

If we assume that *some* of the `args` are scalars, and some are lists, we can wrap the scalars into lists and use the same trick.

```
def concatenate_all(*scalars_or_seqs):
  def to_list(x):
      # TODO: should make it work with generators, too.
      return x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]

  # We use itertools to avoid creating intermediate lists.
  all_items = itertools.chain(*scalars_or_seqs)
  all_lists = itertools.imap(to_list, all_items)
  return reduce(lambda acc, x: concatenate(acc, x), all_lists, EMPTY)
```

If we assume that some of the `args` are *also* nested lists which we need to flatten, you can update the code above to also handle that.

I want to warn you against making the a function that is *too* smart about its arguments. Excessive magic may initially [look neat](http://www.tshirtvortex.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/unicreep.jpg), but in practice becomes too hard to reason about, especially when using such a highly dynamic language as Python, with nearly zero static checks. It's better to push wrapping and flattening to the caller side and make them explicit.

Answer (score 3):

Using `+` for repeated concatenation is not ideal as it keeps creating intermediate `list` objects for each binary concatenation which results in quadratic worst case time-complexity with regard to the combined length. A simpler and better approach would be a nested comprehension which has linear complexity.
This also uses the `*` operator to unpack an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
def concatenate(*terms):
    return [x for t in terms for x in (t if isinstance(t, list) else [t])]

>>> concatenate([3, 4], 5, [], 7, [1])
[3, 4, 5, 7, 1]

>>> concatenate()
[]
```

Comment: Just to make sure, does isinstance(t, list) do the same as type(t) == list?

Comment: It is a little more liberal in that it will also accept instances of `list` subclasses.